# UITableView trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt not working on iOS 14.4 simulator

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios-simulator

I'm building an app that needs to use trailing actions for a UITableView, I configured `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` as follows:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        if indexPath == IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) {
            return nil
        }

        let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") { [weak self] (_, _, completion) in
            self?.onDeleteActionClicked(at: indexPath)
            completion(true)
        }
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = .black
        deleteAction.image = UIImage.sfSymbol(.trash, tintColor: .white)

        let editAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") { [weak self] (_, _, completion) in
            self?.onEditActionClicked(at: indexPath)
            completion(true)
        }
        editAction.backgroundColor = .white
        editAction.image = UIImage.sfSymbol(.edit)

        let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction, editAction])
        configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
        return configuration
    }
```

This implementation works on a physical device and other simulators running iOS 16.1

The delegate is set correctly since `didSelectRowAt` is being called, no gestureRecognizers are added to the cells and seems to be working fine with simulators running iOS 16.1 and physical devices running the same iOS version

Comment: Define "not working". What is actually happening when run on the iOS 14 simulator? Is this delegate method being called or not? If called, what happens when you swipe the cell?

Comment: @HangarRash the method is not being called so I am not seeing any kind of “swipe” behavior

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So apparently for this to work before iOS 15 you have to implement the following method in the DataSource:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Custom logic goes in here
}
```